My figures cannot be placed side by side
I have this code to place six images into two rows (3 images for each row):
\begin{figure}[htbp!]   
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3 \textwidth}

     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 1}
 \end{subfigure} \hfill
 
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 2}
 \end{subfigure} \hfill

 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 3}
 \end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 5}
 \end{subfigure} \hfill


 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 7}
 \end{subfigure} \hfill


 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{6agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 8}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill

 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{7agw-eva.png}
     \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 3}
 \end{subfigure}

    \caption{caption.}
    \label{fig:fig-evaluation}
\end{figure}

But they are shown in vertical positions.

Please always make sure to post full but miniaml examples such that others know which class and packages you are using. Also use images from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe, as we of course does not have your images.

Remember that a blank line gives a new paragraph. So \hfill and then a blanmk line is a bad idea.

@daleif thank you so much. It solves my issue. I did not know that a blank line in the code will be an issue. By removing the blank lines, it is solved.

You can always start a line with % and leave the rest blank.  The is also \@bsphack and \@esphack  for removal with  extreme prejudice.

This works just fine. Be careful with your blank lines, that starts a new paragraph, so they should not be there for the lines that ends with \hfill.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3 \textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 1}
  \end{subfigure} \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 2}
  \end{subfigure} \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
  
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 5}
 \end{subfigure} \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 7}
 \end{subfigure} \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
   \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 8}
 \end{subfigure}

 \medskip
 
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
   \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Cec\_2021\_ Function 3}
 \end{subfigure}

 \caption{Convergence curves for AGWO and other recent algorithms
   during 2500 iterations.}
 \label{fig:agwo-evaluation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

